# How to add noexcept specifier to already defined function type?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20

For example I have type:

```
typedef DWORD WINAPI HANDLER_FUNCTION_EX (DWORD);
```

And I want:

```
static as_noexcept<HANDLER_FUNCTION_EX>::type my_func; // forward declaration
static_assert(noexcept(my_func(0)));
```

I got something like:

```
template<typename>
struct noexcept_trait;

// specialization to infer signature
template<typename Result, typename... Args>
struct noexcept_trait<Result(Args...)>
{
    using as_noexcept = Result(Args...) noexcept;
    using as_throwing = Result(Args...);
};
// since C++17 noexcept-specification is a part of the function type
// so first specialization won't match
template<typename Result, typename... Args>
struct noexcept_trait<Result(Args...) noexcept>
{
    using as_noexcept = Result(Args...) noexcept;
    using as_throwing = Result(Args...);
};

template<typename T>
using add_noexcept_t = typename noexcept_trait<T>::as_noexcept;
template<typename T>
using remove_noexcept_t = typename noexcept_trait<T>::as_throwing;
```

But this code creates totally new type and drops all additional info (calling convention, attributes e.g. `[[deprecated]]`). So it's not safe. How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure `HANDLER_FUNCTION_EX()` isn't throwing? Even if it is a pure C function, if it might call another function indirectly, that other function might throw. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24362616/does-the-c-standard-mandate-that-c-linkage-functions-are-noexcept) for an interesting read.

Comment: @G.Sliepen `HANDLER_FUNCTION_EX` is just function type name. Actual function is `my_func` and defined with `noexcept`, so I'm sure it won't throw.

Comment: If your compiler extends the type system to have calling convention modifiers, can’t you add more specializations to handle those cases?  It’s painfully long, to be sure, but it’s not difficult.

Comment: @DavisHerring `__attribute__((stdcall))` or `__stdcall` is not part of function type, so all specializations are conflicting (error: class template has already been defined)

Comment: @DavisHerring it was failing because in x64 mode msvc treats __cdecl same as __stdcall.
if I choose x86 target, they are treated as different types. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200717-00/?p=103989

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
template<typename Result, typename... Args>
struct noexcept_trait<Result __stdcall(Args...)>
{
    using as_noexcept = Result __stdcall(Args...) noexcept;
    using as_throwing = Result __stdcall(Args...);
};
```

and similar elsewhere.  But you should only do this if `!is_same_v< void(*)(), void(__stdcall *)() >`.  If `__stdcall` does nothing on your platform, you'll get a conflict here.

Attributes are explicitly not part of the type system.  `[[deprecated]]` applies to the type definition itself, not the thing being defined.  The very use of that type to create the alias is `[[deprecated]]`.