# Python with c++ using ctypes. Pass string from python as function argument

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, ctypes

I need to pass a string to a C++ function and have it return the string, but when I try to do this I get an error:

```yaml
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000005
```

> **Code python 3.11**:

```py
import ctypes
import os

lib = ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "testDllForPy.dll"))

def encode(data:str) -> str:
    # my_str_b = "Hello".encode('utf-8')
    # c_str = ctypes.c_char_p(my_str_b)
    c_str = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer("Hello", 5)
    lib.encode.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
    my_new_str = lib.encode("Hello", 5)
    print(my_new_str)
```

> **Code C++**:

```cpp
#include <string>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) std::string encode(char* data, unsigned int len)
{   
    //char data[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
    unsigned short* s_data = new unsigned short[len];
    unsigned short* r_data = new unsigned short[len];

    char* res_data = new char[len*2];

    for (int i=0; i < len; i++) {
        short chr_num = short(char(*(data + i)));
        unsigned short salt = rand() % 512 + 512;

        s_data[i] = salt;
        r_data[i] = chr_num + salt;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= len*2; i+=2) {
        res_data[i] = char(r_data[i]);
        res_data[i+1] = char(s_data[i+1]);
    }

    return res_data;
}
```

I just started learning ctypes and c++ so don't judge too harshly. I don't know how to correctly pass a string to a function in such a situation, and I can't understand the ctypes documentation.

Comment: `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) std::string` you cannot export functions that return classes. You will need to return a pointer to a buffer (and you need that buffer to stay in memory for as long as it is needed)

Comment: That last loop in your C function indexes arrays out-of-bounds. You aren't cleaning up your memory allocations. I suggest you take a class on C. Also, c_char_p might be expecting null termination, which you aren't accounting for anywhere.

Comment: @PepijnKramer "you cannot export functions that return classes" This is absolutely not true.

Comment: `c_char_p` means `char*`, not `std::string`. You can't use C++ classes with `ctypes`.

Comment: The first letter in `ctypes` stands for C the programming language. C++ however is not C, and C++ types are not C types. Not `std::string` at any rate. You need to either rewrite your C++ code such that it is usable from C (then it will be usable from Python too), or use a C++/Python bridge.  I recommend [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11).

Comment: Also, you;re missing ***argtypes*** ([\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546)). For a comprehensive example (more or less similar than yours), check [\[SO\]: Pass str as an int array to a Python C extended function (extended using SWIG) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47296602/4788546).

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI You can from a dll, but extern "C" means that export a "C" compatible function (maybe you can guess the mangled names but it is not recommended). Also you should be very sure not to let any C++ exceptions escape. So all in all much safer to make a real "C" front end to the underlying "C++" code

Comment: @PepijnKramer "means that export a "C" compatible function" The standard never says anything like that. It says that language linkage is implementation-defined and language-dependent. No implementation that I know defines 'extern "C"' to mean "this thing must be C compatible". It generally just means "this name is not mangled". It is very useful if you want to use human-readable names with `dlsym`/`GetProcAddress`.

Comment: I haven't used extern "C" in a long time so yes I am partly wrong there.  but I am sure the exception bit is true. [can extern "C" exceptions throw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845681/can-c-functions-marked-as-extern-c-throw) mentions this too.  And the object stuff seems possible (https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp#cpp-objs-passed-to-c)

Comment: @PepijnKramer Again, the standard says nothing like that. It all [works](https://godbolt.org/z/oK8aqMbz3) for the most part (maybe MSVC has quirks, as usual).